# How to write budget constraint if the agent sell the goods that buy

Tags: microeconomics, game-theory, utility, consumer-theory, self-study

Della’s utility is $U(G,R)$

G is the consumption of gasoline per week

R is the the consumption of other goods

[image]

Just help me to write down budget constraint.

I think that

$$R*1+(G-20)*10+20*1=1000+10*X$$

where

X is the amount of the gasoline that she sell on the black market.

Comment: Budget constraint is simply : $R+10(G-20)+20=1000$

Comment: @Amit but the agent also sells gasoline purchased. How can we show this in the budget constraint? Your budget constraint doesn’t tell this statement.

Comment: @Amit then how can we find how much she consume and how much she sell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agent is a buyer of gasoline in the black market if his consumption of gasoline exceeds 20 i.e. $G > 20$, and he buys $(G-20)$ units from the black market in this case. So, his budget constraint is $R + 20 + 10(G-20)=100$

Likewise, agent is a seller of gasoline in the black market if his consumption of gasoline is below 20 i.e. $G \leq 20$. In this case, he sells $(20-G)$ units in the black market. So, his budget constraint is $R + 20=100 + 10(20-G)$

To conclude, his budget constraint (in all cases) is $R + 20 + 10(G-20)=100$.

Comment: Thank you sooo much.  Thanks to your helps, I not only understand the answer but especially also understand how I should think when I see such type of questions. Thanks a lot. 

Comment: Dear Amit, I hope you’re doing well. I have two questions, I solved,  but I stack at some points. When you have time, I will be happy if you solve. Many thanks.

Comment: First question https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/22722/consumer-theory-signaling

Comment: Second question https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/22720/duopoly-game-asymmetric-info